# Mistakenly printing only one object within an array

Tags: java, arrays, project

The instructions for the assignment insist upon my use of arrays -- not arraylists or any other potential options. Also, any assigned parameters are there specifically because that is what my professor requested in her instructions

Basically, I am successfully printing the amount of objects that I need and the format of the entries, etc, is correct -- but I am only retrieving the contents of one object, repeatedly. I have tried messing around with re-assignments of static and non-static, but that seems to only create more problems. TestEmployee4 is dependent upon a text file but the problem definitely does not reside within my retrieval of the text so it is essentially irrelevant. TestEmployee4 is also dependent upon a previously utilized class, ScottEmployee2 (which is why it is full of comments).

My only goal is to get this program to run correctly -- at this point, I am not worried about the copious amounts of questionable code presented within this project. I cannot consult further with my professor until Monday.

This is the contents of TestEmployee4:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestEmployee4
{

  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException

 {
 ScottEmployee2[] employees = createEmployeeArrayFromFile();
 createEmployeeArrayFromFile();
 printEmployeeArray(employees); 
}


public static ScottEmployee2[] createEmployeeArrayFromFile() throwsFileNotFoundException
 {
    File file = new File("employees.txt"); 
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner( new File("employees.txt") );

ScottEmployee2[] employees = new ScottEmployee2[10];

int index = 0;


while (inputFile.hasNextLine() && index < employees.length) // && index < employees.length

{  
      String dummyNumber = inputFile.nextLine();
      int theNumber = Integer.parseInt(dummyNumber);
      String theName = inputFile.nextLine();
      String theDepartment = inputFile.nextLine();
      String thePosition = inputFile.nextLine();
      String dummySalary = inputFile.nextLine();
      double theSalary = Double.parseDouble(dummySalary);
      String dummyRank = inputFile.nextLine();
      int theRank = Integer.parseInt(dummyRank);


      employees[index] = new ScottEmployee2(theNumber, theName, theDepartment, thePosition, theSalary, theRank);
      index++;
}
return employees;
}


public static void printEmployeeArray(ScottEmployee2[]employees)
{
for(ScottEmployee2 i : employees){   
ScottEmployee2.displayEmployee();

}


}

}
```

And this is the contents of ScottEmployee2:

```
public class ScottEmployee2

{
  private static int number; 
  private static String name; 
  private static String department; 
  private static String position; 
  private static double salary; 
  private static int rank; 
  private static double percentage; 
  private static double modSalary;


 public ScottEmployee2(int theNumber, String theName, String theDepartment,String thePosition, double theSalary, int theRank) 
 {
  number = theNumber; 
  name = theName;
  department = theDepartment;
  position = thePosition;
 salary = theSalary;
 rank = theRank;

}

   public ScottEmployee2(int theNumber, String theName) 
{
  number = theNumber; 
 name = theName;
 department = null;
 position = null;
 salary = 0;
 rank = 0;
 percentage = 0;
  modSalary = 0;
 }
  /**
   * Sets the salary.
   * @param theSalary Holds the value of salary.
   */

   public void setSalary(double theSalary) 
   {
    salary = theSalary; 
   }

   /**
    * Created to provide the accessor and mutator methods for each field value
    * as instructed to meet the requirements of the project.
    * @return salary, a double value
    */

    public double getSalary()
    {
    return salary;
    }


   /**
   * Created to provide the accessor and mutator methods for each field value
   * as instructed to meet the requirements of the project. setNumber is the mutator.
   * @param theNumber Stores an integer, the value of a number.
   */

   public void setNumber(int theNumber) 
   {
   number = theNumber;
   }

  /**
   * Created to provide the accessor and mutator methods for each field value
   * as instructed to meet the requirements of the project. getNumber is the accessor.
   * @return number, an integer.
   */

   public int getNumber()
   {
   return number; 
   }

/**
* Created to provide the accessor and mutator methods for each field value
* as instructed to meet the requirements of the project. setName is the mutator.
* @param theName Stores a String, a name.
*/

 public static void setName(String theName) 
 {
 name = theName;
 }

/**
* Created to provide the accessor and mutator methods for each field value
* as instructed to meet the requirements of the project. getName is the accessor because
* it gets a value from a class field but does not modify it.
* @return name, a String, the employee's name.
*/

public static String getName()
{
return name; 
}

/**
* Created to provide the accessor and mutator methods for each field value
* as instructed to meet the requirements of the project. theDepartment is the mutator because
* it stores or changes a value in a field.
* @param theDepartment Stores a String, the department that the employee works in.
*/

public void setDepartment(String theDepartment) 
{
department = theDepartment ; 
}

/**
* Created to provide the accessor and mutator methods for each field value
* as instructed to meet the requirements of the project. getDepartment is the accessor because
* it gets a value from a class field but does not modify it.
* @return department, a String, the employee's department.
*/

public String getDepartment()
{
 return department; 
}

/**
* Created to provide the accessor and mutator methods for each field value
* as instructed to meet the requirements of the project. thePosition is the mutator because
* it stores or changes a value in a field.
* @param thePosition Stores a String, the position that the employee holds.
*/

 public void setPosition(String thePosition) 
 {
 position = thePosition ; 
 }

/**
* Created to provide the accessor and mutator methods for each field value
* as instructed to meet the requirements of the project. getPosition is the accessor because
* it gets a value from a class field but does not modify it.
* @return position, a String, the position that the employee holds.
*/

 public String getPosition()
 {
 return position; 
 }

 /**
  * Created to provide the accessor and mutator methods for each field value
* as instructed to meet the requirements of the project. theDepartment is the mutator because
* it stores or changes a value in a field.
* @param theRank Stores an integer, the employee's rank.
*/

 public void setRank(int theRank) 
 {
  rank = theRank; 
 }

/** 
*Accessor method.
*@return rank, an integer, the employee's rank.
*/

 public int getRank()
 {
  return rank; 
 }

  /**
  * Mutator method.
   * @param percent, stores a double, the percentage
  * to be applied to the current salary.
  * Contains an if statement, to filter out results
  * that are out of bounds -- less than 1% or greater than 25% 
  */

  public void applyRaise(double percent) 
   {
   percentage = percent;

   if (percentage < 1 || percentage > 25)
   {
  System.out.println("NO RAISE APPLIED");
  percentage = 0;
   }
   modSalary = salary;
    salary = modSalary + (salary * (percentage * 0.01));            
    }

  /** 
   * Accessor method.
   * @return percentage, the percent to be applied to salary 
   * to give the raise. 
   */

  public double theRaise()
  {
   return percentage; 
 }

/** 
* Prints a formatted salary. Per instructions, this method does
* not define any parameters or return any values.
*/

 public void printSalary() 
 {
  System.out.printf("$%,.2f\n", salary);
 }


  /** 
 * Method that returns a boolean value of true if employee rank is greater
 * than five. Otherwise, it returns false.
   */

   public static boolean checkBonus()
  {
   {
   if (rank > 5)
   {
   return true;
  }
 else 
   {
  return false;
 }}
 }  

/** 
* Method to print employee's information to standard output. The employee    number is formatted to
* nine digits and salary is formatted as currency. This method calls checkBonus() for a value of 
* true or false. If true, an additional statement is printed. Otherwise, no bonus statement is printed.
*/

  public static void displayEmployee()
  {
 System.out.println("Name: " + name);
 System.out.printf("Employee Number: %09d", number);
 System.out.println("\nDepartment: " + department + "\nPosition: " + position); 
 System.out.printf("Salary: $%,.2f", salary); 
 System.out.println("\nRank: " + rank);
 if (checkBonus() == true)
 {
   System.out.println("Bonus: $1,000");

  }
 else
 {
 // do nothing  
 }



}
}
```

Comment: Regarding the note about a deadline (now deleted), please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I appreciate that Stack Overflow veterans are sometimes regarded as prone to being a bit spiky, but it is best not to make reference to that in your questions. The best approach is to [ask as confidently as you can](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366264/how-can-we-encourage-new-authors-to-ask-confident-questions), with the minimum of fluff and chat.

Comment: @Parth: I agree there was too much material in the question, but the initial material contained the educator's restrictions on the allowed solutions, which is probably relevant. I have restored a couple of sentences of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there are a few things that I'd like to go over with you, and some go past the answer to this particular problem you have.

To start, let's work through the problem at hand.
Whenever you go to print your array of Employees you do the following code:

```
public static void printEmployeeArray(ScottEmployee2[]employees)
{
    for(ScottEmployee2 i : employees){   
        ScottEmployee2.displayEmployee();

    }
}
```

There are a few issues with this code. First thing's first, you don't have a space between ScottEmployee2[] and employees. Next,you're callting displayEmployee() on the class ScottEMployee2 rather than the object you have in your for loop. This is what you should do:

```
public static void printEmployeeArray(ScottEmployee2[]employees)
{
    for(ScottEmployee2 i : employees){   
        i.displayEmployee();

    }
```

Now, going beyond just this quick fix I want to talk to you about some of your code conventions. First off, this while loop should be made a for loop like so:

```
for (i = 0; i < employees.length i ++){
  if(!inputFile.hasNextLine()){
      break;
  }
  String dummyNumber = inputFile.nextLine();
  int theNumber = Integer.parseInt(dummyNumber);
  String theName = inputFile.nextLine();
  String theDepartment = inputFile.nextLine();
  String thePosition = inputFile.nextLine();
  String dummySalary = inputFile.nextLine();
  double theSalary = Double.parseDouble(dummySalary);
  String dummyRank = inputFile.nextLine();
  int theRank = Integer.parseInt(dummyRank);


  employees[index] = new ScottEmployee2(theNumber, theName, theDepartment, thePosition, theSalary, theRank);
  index++;
}
```

This is simply because it is more stylistically appropriate. Second, in your ScottEmployee class, you have several methods as static when they shouldn't be. Thoes are:

- displayEmployee();
- checkBonus();
- setName(); //You don't want all Employees to have the same name right?
- getName();

In addition, almost all of your fields in that class shouldn't be static as they don't need to stay consistent through each instantiation of the class. This means your fields should look like this:

```
private static int number; 
private int rank;
private String name,department,position; 
private double salary,percentage,modSalary;
```

The use of static should only be if you should have a field work across all instances of the class. having number static means whatever you set it to when you make a new ScottEmployee2 will be what is is for the next one you make unless you change it.

I certianly hope that all of this will help you in your adventures of coding! Pelase let me know if there's anything else I can help you with!

Comment: Hello, thank you for your prompt and thorough response. Unfortunately, after implementing the suggestions so far, I have a massive nullPointerException issue: java.lang.NullPointerException at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:267)

Comment: where is the NullPointerException at? Please upload your error output to https://www.pastebin.com and comment the link

Comment: Here is the error output via pastebin.com: https://pastebin.com/UZE6jAP9. It doesn't seem overly specific to me and I am limited to the use of DrJava for my class so I don't see line numbers nor can I click the error text in an attempt to point me in the right direction. :\

Comment: However, I did catch the fact that I had not written my main method in TestEmployee4 as static which was a stupid mistake on my part. And the issue has now been resolved!!! It is functioning properly! Thank you so much for your assistance.

Comment: @Kwright02: regarding your now-deleted comment on another answer here: it is not a problem for several people to post the same thing. This is bound to happen if there is one obvious way to fix it. The only legitimate grounds for complaint are if (a) an answer is so short it is not likely to be useful to other readers, or (b) if it has been plagiarised without attribution. Where you suspect plagiarism, a mod flag is the best way to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

When you're doing your for/each loop you have

```
ScottEmployee2.displayEmployee();
```

However you assign the variable `i` for the ScottEmployee2 object. Try instead:

```
i.displayEmployee();
```

Also a few (hopefully helpful) remarks about your code.

In one of your methods you have something like:

```
if(//something) {
   //Do something
}
else {
//do nothing
}
```

However you do not need an else to every if statement. You can simply do:

```
if(//something) {
  //do something
}
```

And leave of the else part. Also this is just for conventions but it is customary to have the brackets like the code above, where you have the opening bracket on the same line of the if statement. Overall, a very simple mistake.